# Помощь в коррекции кода, Кривая камера в кривых руках

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера, pivot

Помогите пожалуйста сделать более глубокую настройку камеры, это все чудо и поворот персонажа работает через Pivot но Pivot автоматически создается в ногах персонажа, и камера постоянно смотрит вниз, как это можно исправить?
Что бы Pivot создавался хотя бы в голове и персонаж смотрел хотя бы прямо, а лучше, что бы камеру можно было подкрутить, ну там, в бок отодвинуть или углы настроить.

[image: Камера]

[image: Кривая камера]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RCameraControls : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public bool useOffsetValues;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    public Transform pivot;
    public float maxViewAngle;
    public float minViewAngle;
    public bool InvertY;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (!useOffsetValues)
        {
            offset = target.position - transform.position;
        }

        pivot.transform.position = target.transform.position;
        pivot.transform.parent = target.transform;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        //Поворот камеры по иксу
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;
        target.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);
        // поворот по игрику
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotateSpeed;
        pivot.Rotate(-vertical, 0, 0);
        if (InvertY)
        {
            pivot.Rotate(vertical, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            pivot.Rotate(-vertical, 0, 0);
        }

        //Верхний и нижний угол камеры
        if(pivot.rotation.eulerAngles.x > maxViewAngle && pivot.rotation.eulerAngles.x < 180f)
        {
            pivot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(maxViewAngle, 0, 0);
        }

        if(pivot.rotation.eulerAngles.x > 180 && pivot.rotation.eulerAngles.x < 360f + minViewAngle)
        {
            pivot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(360f + minViewAngle, 0, 0);
        }

        //движение камеры в зависимости от позиции
        float desiredYAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
        float desiredXAngle = pivot.eulerAngles.x;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(desiredXAngle , desiredYAngle, 0);
        transform.position = target.position - ( rotation * offset);

        //изминение позиции
        if(transform.position.y < target.position.y)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, target.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        transform.LookAt(target);
    } 
}
```

Comment: а вы какой версией юнити пользуетесь? Чем вас не устраивает Cinemachine? Ассет от юнитеков для всяких интересных штук с камерами)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вместо position и rotation вам стоит использовать localPosition и localRotation. Они измеряются относительно парента, а не глобальных координатах.